# Check my logic? Mapping of subsets to subsets proof (Lemma to Cantor-Berenstein)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Self-studying topology (well, at the moment, set theory) I'm tasked with this proof, as a lemma leading up to the Cantor-Berenstein theorem.

Suppose for each subset C of a set A, there is some $C' \subset A$ such that $C \subset D \Rightarrow C' \subset D' $. Prove there exists $E \subset A$ such that $E = E'$.

I recognize I'm proving there's a ... fixed point? ... for a function mapping subsets of A to subsets of A in this manner.

Following the book's suggestion, I define $E = \bigcup \lbrace C \in \mathscr{P}(A) |   C \subset C' \rbrace$.

Showing $E\subset E'$ is straightforward:

Let $x$ be an element of  E. Then for some $C\subset E$ defined as above, $x \in C,$ which means $x \in C'$ by our definition of E. But also note that $C \subset E \Rightarrow C' \subset E'$ by our initial hypothesis. Since $x \in C'$, this means $x\in E'$. Thus $x \in E \Rightarrow x \in E'$ and $E \subset E'$

**It's showing that $E' \subset E$ that I'm more unsure about:**

Suppose $x\in A$ where $x \notin E $. Let F be the set $\lbrace x \rbrace \cup E$.

Now, note first that since $E\subset F,$ we can conclude $E' \subset F'$, and with our previous result this means $E \subset F'$.

However, it is also the case that F cannot be a subset of F', for if it were, F would be a subset of E (by the definition of E). This means that F cannot be the same set as E', for if it were, F would be a subset of F'. Additionally, F cannot be a subset of E', for if it were, F would be a subset of F'.

Now, $F\cap E'$ must contain E, since E is a subset of both sets, but F must differ from E'. Since $F - E = \lbrace x \rbrace$, and $E \subset E'$, this implies $F - E' \subset F - E$. Also, F - E must be nonempty since F is not a subset of E'. Thus $F - E' = \lbrace x \rbrace$.

That is, we have shown that for any element x not in E, it is not in E'. By the converse, this implies $E' \subset E$.

Thus, for E defined as above, E = E'.

Comment: This is the Knaster–Tarski lemma, by the way.

Comment: Oh cool thanks! That was never mentioned in my text. Does my logic work or is there an awful hole somewhere?